# Экономический бот Дискорд TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py, type-error

**Пишу экономического бота на дискорд  вот код:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import sqlite3
from config import settings

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['PREFIX'])
client.remove_command('help')

connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT,
        rep INT,
        lvl INT
    )""")
    connection.commit()

    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
                connection.commit()
            else:
                pass
    connection.commit()
    print('BOT successfuly connected')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
        connection.commit()
    else:
        pass


@client.command(aliases = ['balance', 'cash'])
async def __balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Уровень доверия пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
        ))
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
        description = f"""Уровень доверия пользователя **{member}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
        ))

client.run(settings['TOKEN'])
```

После ввода команды .balance (у меня префикс .), консоль выдает ошибку :

```
Ignoring exception in command __balance:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\discord BOTS\py bots\InnokyECONOMY\bot.py", line 47, in __balance
    description = f"""Уровень доверия пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: В той часте кода что вы дали я не нашел никакой переменной `subscriptable`, может где-то в другой части кода?

Comment: код из данного файла это весь. Есть еще файл config.py 

`
settings = {
    'TOKEN': 'Скрыто',
    'NAME BOT': 'InnokyCord',
    'ID': Скрыто,
    'PREFIX': '.'
}
`

И server.db и там просто символы

Answer (score 0):

Здесь проблема заключается в том что ты пытаешься обратиться по индексу к None
`description = f"""Уровень доверия пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**""" ))`
то есть ты обращаешься к `[0]` через `None` и вот из-за этого вся суета начинается

Comment: только в чём прикол как задать значение своего или другого кошелька?

Comment: Называется ютуб в помощь